# Need to concatenate the date and integer to get date time value

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have an input data file like this, with the column names not included in  the data file (`Date`, `Desc`, `Timestamp1`, `Timestamp2`):

```
2016-01-01, AAA, 330, 1430

2016-01-02, ABA, 130, 930
```

I need output like this:

```
2016-01-01, AAA, 2016-01-01 03:30, 2016-01-01 14:30

2016-01-02, ABA, 2016-01-02 01:30, 2016-01-02 09:30
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I really appreciate your response. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 9):

It could be done with simple string replacement like below using `awk`, but beware that this method is probably not too reliable if your format changes slightly or the input data is not valid.

```bsh
awk -F, '/,/{printf "%s, %s, %s %02d:%02d, %s %02d:%02d\n",$1,$2,$1,int($3/100),$3%100,$1,int($4/100),$4%100}' YOUR_FILE.CSV
```

Or with the `awk` code formatted for better readability:

```
/,/ {
    printf "%s, %s, %s %02d:%02d, %s %02d:%02d\n",
           $1, $2, 
           $1, int($3 / 100), $3 % 100,
           $1, int($4 / 100), $4 % 100
}
```

In plain English, this runs on every line that contains a comma (to avoid processing empty lines) and just prints out the respective column values (input is comma separated due to `-F,`) with the specified format:

- 1st column (date), comma, 2nd column (desc), comma,
- 1st column (date), 3rd column value / 100 (hour of timestamp1), colon, 3rd column value modulo 100 (minutes of timestamp1), comma
- 1st column (date), 4th column value / 100 (hour of timestamp2), colon, 4th column value modulo 100 (minutes of timestamp2)

The result on your input data in question would be

```
2016-01-01,  AAA, 2016-01-01 03:30, 2016-01-01 14:30
2016-01-02,  ABA, 2016-01-02 01:30, 2016-01-02 09:30
```

Comment: The main difference to my solutions is the use of `sprintf` to build the output which I like a lot better than my fumbling with strings and variables.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `awk` to achieve the desired output. I'm not sure if the blank lines between the input and output are actually there or just a formatting issue, but I considered them in the command.

```
awk -F, '{if (NF) { print $1 "," $2 ", " $1 " " sprintf("%02d", int($3 / 100)) ":" $3 % 100 ", " $1 " " sprintf("%02d", int($4 / 100)) ":" $4 % 100 } else { print }}' < input.txt > output.txt
```

What this does is as follows:

- `-F,` sets the input field separator of `awk` to `,` so the input is split correctly.
- `if (NF)` checks if the number of input fields is greater than zero. This is for the handling of empty lines. If the line is empty the `else` part at the end of the command will print a blank line.
- `print` command prints the fields specified:

  - `$1` is the first field from the input, the date
  - `","` prints a literal comma
  - `$2` is the second field, the description
  - `", "` prints the next comma
  - `$1` prints the date again for your timestamp
  - `" "` adds the space between date and time
  - `sprintf("%02d", int($3 / 100))` first calculates the hour part of the time by dividing the time by 100, discarding the decimals (`int()` does that) and prints that number with leading zeros with two digits (`%02d%` as format string for `sprintf()` handles that)
  - `":"` is again just a literal colon
  - `$3 % 100` is a modulo operation giving the remainder of the division of the time by 100 and therefore the minutes
  - `", " $1 " " sprintf("%02d", int($4 / 100)) ":" $4 % 100` is the same for the second timestamp
- `else` part is explained above with the `if`.
- `< input.txt` tells the shell to read `awk`s input from the specified file.
- `> output.txt` tells the shell to write `awk`s output to that file.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a perl variant (whose `s/pattern/replacement/` has an `e` modifier that allows evaluation of an expression in the replacement):

```
perl -F', ' -lpe '$_ = join ",", @F[0,1], map { 
    s/(\d?\d)(\d\d)/sprintf "%s %02d:%02d", $F[0], $1, $2/e ; $_ 
  } @F[2,3] if @F
' file
2016-01-01, AAA, 2016-01-01 03:30, 2016-01-01 14:30

2016-01-02, ABA, 2016-01-02 01:30, 2016-01-02 09:30
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response. IT is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Following Perl version with a get-the-basic-elements and reformat-them strategy

```
perl -ne '/((.*?),.*?, )(\d*)(\d\d), (\d*)(\d\d)/ and 
            printf("%s%s %02d:%s, %s %02d:%s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$2,$5,$6)'
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I really appreciate such a good solution.